# load mongo db data to .net core app takes too much time

Tags: c#, mongodb, asp.net-core

I am searching for the postal code in the 100k data. all data available in the mongo DB cloud. I am searching for data on that. but it takes too much time to find the data. any suggestions on that?

here is the code for searching data in Mongo DB

```
city = adminRepository.AllNewArea.Where(e => e.COUNTRY.ToLower() == country.CountryName.ToLower().ToString() && e.POSTAL == PostalCode).FirstOrDefault();
```

database structure

[image]

Comment: You said the data is in the mongo DB cloud, so are you sure that it is the finding of data that is taking a long time, or the transmission of data?

Comment: I have checked with local mongo DB too. it is taking time in the local Mongo DB as well.

Comment: In any NoSql db like Mongo, ideally its a document you are searching. Usually there is an id indexed. If you are searching not on id, you have to make sure that the other fields are indexed.

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific and explain the problem in detail along with the environment you currently are on?

Comment: @SalmanKazmi as i have mentioned above i am using mongo DB as database and .net core 2.2 as a framework. i want to search for postal code in the mongo db document. like the user has entered a postal code like '362001' then i need to find that this code is available in the database or not? FYI i have already added more then 1 lacs record in the database. and i need to search in those records

Comment: @AzharKhorasany please click on database structure link in description

Comment: @jeet, you need to make sure that Country and Postal fields are indexed. You need to look at the configuration of the document collection in Mongo. Google around how will you index custom fields.

Comment: How large is the database?  Is the Postal Code a Key in the database (index) ?  See : https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/wiredtiger/

Comment: Have a look at https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/optimize-query-performance-with-indexes-and-projections/#create-indexes-to-support-queries